# Import data to OMNET++

Tags: excel, plugins, omnet++

I am trying to model a network in OMNET++. What I have is a text file (can be in an Excel file format) with nodes' names, list of interfaces, and interface connections. What I like to do is to write a program (perhaps a plug-in) to feed this file to OMNET++ and (automatically) create .ned and .cc based on this file. The rationale is that there is a long list of nodes/interfaces, that makes it difficult to do it manually, and possibly a change in the connections makes it difficult to recreate it, undelss it is done automatically. Could you point to some links/websites/documents, so that I learn how to write a plugin to read the information and create the nodes and their connections automatically? Obviously, the node types and characteristics could be modified in the plugin as necessary later.

### An example is like:

(some other information there)...

cr1.atl-cr1.hst cr1.atl cr1.hst     2488
cr1.kcy-cr1.wdc cr1.kcy cr1.wdc     2488
cr1.atl-cr2.atl cr1.atl cr2.atl     10000
cr2.atl-cr1.wdc cr1.wdc cr2.atl     2488
...

where the second column is the source node, the third column is the destination node, and the first column is the link (firstNode-secondNode). The 4th column is the capacity/delay or other information of the link.

Comment: Why do you need `.cc` code? If it is only the `.ned` files you need then it should be not too hard to write a parser which reads a text file and builds the appropriate `.ned`.

Comment: I am not sure yet, if I will only get the topology from the Excel file or might also get some functionality from it, that should be included in .cc file. But for now, I am happy to get .ned file. How do you mean by writing a parser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this to be as flexible as possible, I would recommend writing a small Python script that reads a .csv file and renders .ned files as needed.

You might even consider using a templating engine like Mako. Quoting from its website, Mako is pretty straightforward to use:

```
from mako.template import Template
print(Template("hello ${data}!").render(data="world"))
```

Comment: Thank you Christoph. I am not familiar with Python scripts very well. I am going to look into that now. I edited the question with an example of the sort of information I have in the Excel file.